# Autofill an area of cells dependant on the userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform, autofill

I have built code for a userform that will complete certain tasks depending on the scenario. Everything works, but the autofill code I have in place for scenario 3 (Sheets JH and CT) are not working. While in the same scenario the autofill for worksheet MRFL is doing as asked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ColA As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference
Dim ColB As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Criteria1 As Boolean
Dim Criteria2 As Boolean
Dim C As Range




With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This gets the last row on column A
    For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through the whole column
    On Error Resume Next
        'If you have duplicated entries this will throw an error
        ColA.Add C.Value, C.Row 'add the values from column A to DictA, also store it's row for later purposes
        ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row 'add the values from column B to DictB, also store it's row for later purposes
    Next C
    'Criterias will give value of True if matched or False if not
    Criteria1 = ColA.Exists(ComboBox2.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColA Dictionary
    Criteria2 = ColB.Exists(ComboBox1.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColB Dictionary
    If Criteria1 And Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 1
       Call linepick
    ElseIf Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 2
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
         Call linepick
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Resize(, 5).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ElseIf Not Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 3
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Resize(, 21).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Cells(LastRow, "AE") = TextBox1.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 4).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 4).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JH").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Resize(, 44).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(LastRow, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Resize(, 5).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
 End With
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
 Unload Me
 End Sub
```

Comment: You missed some `Rows.Count` that are not fully qualified, possibly the root of your problem? i.e.: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "B")...` evaluates to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B")...` which might work because `Sheets("MFRL")` is your active sheet... but for the others...

Comment: I've edited your code, but can't be certain on the correct ranges, I've just fixed the obvious parts. I don't see why the bordering would work, given your `Rows.Count` was still of the `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to my comment, I've took the liberty to fix your code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ColA As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference
Dim ColB As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Criteria1 As Boolean
Dim Criteria2 As Boolean
Dim C As Range

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb.Sheets("MFRL")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This gets the last row on column A
    For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through the whole column
    On Error Resume Next
        'If you have duplicated entries this will throw an error
        ColA.Add C.Value, C.Row 'add the values from column A to DictA, also store it's row for later purposes
        ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row 'add the values from column B to DictB, also store it's row for later purposes
    Next C
    'Criterias will give value of True if matched or False if not
    Criteria1 = ColA.Exists(ComboBox2.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColA Dictionary
    Criteria2 = ColB.Exists(ComboBox1.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColB Dictionary
    If Criteria1 And Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 1
        Call linepick

    ElseIf Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 2
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        Call linepick
        .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 3)
        .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

    ElseIf Not Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 3
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 3)
        .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

        With wb.Sheets("CT")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 21)
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Resize(1, 22).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With

        With wb.Sheets("JH")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
            .Cells(LastRow, "AE") = TextBox1.Value
            .Cells(LastRow, "AE").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 4).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "AE").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 4)
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 44).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End If
End With

    wb.RefreshAll
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** The destination must include the source range.

**EDIT2:** fixed some problems in code

Use the debugger to check if the ranges are what you expect them to be, i.e.:

```vb
Debug.Print "CT Range: " & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).Address
Debug.Print "MFRL Range: " & wb.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(wb.Sheets("MFRL").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 21).Address
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate your code but nothing seems to happen. Do you see anything wrong with just the autofill that seems off since the bordering works? Thanks

Comment: also the lastrow that I had a typo in was a typo, not sure if that changes the answer. The "Monthly FGL Report" should be "JH" instead

Comment: I can't really see nothing wrong to be honest... I've corrected some duplicate resizes, but other than that, without seeing the worksheet or knowing what you expect to see, is hard for me to guess. I've added in the answer a method of debugging... see if it helps.

Comment: It looks to me like you are only trying to copy the values accross? Shouldn't use Autofill, but just `Range.Value = Range.Value` instead. Or if you want formulas, then `Range.Formula = `Range.Formula`...

Comment: Right, which ranges are you trying to fill? Sheet CT & JH from MFRL? or MFRL from CT & JH?. Because at the moment your code is only filling (or trying) the sheet MFRL.

Comment: I am trying to autofill cells on all 3 of the sheets for Scenario 3

Comment: Would you like to look at my workbook I could forward it to you if that would be easier to show you what I am doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194461/discussion-between-darxyde-and-tmacjoshua).

Comment: Hey could you take a look at what I mentioned in the chat. I can make it a question if you would like.